# if $\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty x^n )(\sum_0^\infty x^{2n})$ what is $a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

if $$\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty x^n )(\sum_0^\infty x^{2n})$$

what is $a_n$?

Here is my approach

let $b_n= 1$ and $c_n= x^n$

Then by forming / relating to cauchy product we can conlude that the product is equal to :

$$\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n$$

where $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k c_{n-k} = \sum x^{n-k}= x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^0 = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

What do you think about my approach? I feel like there is something wrong with it. If not - could you provide a different approach? By the way depending on the way I solve - I keep finding different answers. I also ended up with $a_n=\frac{3+2n+(-1)^n}{4}$ without using cauchy product.

Comment: Letting $c_n=x^n$ is going to be a mistake. It is really $$c_n=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ even}\\0&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ The point is, your coefficients should not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write the first sum on the RHS as a geometrical series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n =\dfrac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} \ \ \iff$$

$$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k =\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} \ \ \iff$$

$$\tag{1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}x^k - \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}x^{k+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}.$$

Setting $K:=k+1 \ \iff \ k=K-1$, (1) becomes:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k}x^k - \sum_{K=1}^\infty a_{K-1}x^{K} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$$

$$a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k}-a_{k-1}) x^k =\sum_0^\infty x^{2n} $$

An immediate consequence is that $a_0=1$ ; then, for positive indices, identitifying the coefficients in the LHS and RHS, two cases occur, depending if they correspond to odd or even exponents:

$$\begin{cases}k&=&2n+1& \ \implies \ & a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}=0\\k&=&2n& \ \implies \ & a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}=1 \end{cases}$$

In other words: $$\begin{cases}a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}\\a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+1 \end{cases}.$$

Summarizing, we have a unit increase at even steps, and no increase at odd steps.

Hence, taking into account value $a_0=1$, we get the following explicit formula for the general term:

> $$a_n=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the geometric summation formula $\displaystyle\sum x^n=\dfrac1{1-x}$,

$$A=\frac1{1-x}\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac1{4(1+x)}+\frac1{4(1-x)}+\frac1{2(1-x)^2}\\
=\frac1{4(1+x)}+\frac1{4(1-x)}+\frac12\frac d{dx}\frac x{1-x}$$ so that

$$a_n=\frac14(-1)^n+\frac14+\frac12(n+1).$$

This is a *generating function* approach.

Comment: What you've done in the first line - is there some sort of a general method

Comment: What do you call the first line ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally

$$\sum_0^\infty c_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n )(\sum_0^\infty b_nx^{n})$$

Then define $b_{2k+1} =0$

$$\sum_0^\infty c_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n )(\sum_0^\infty b_{2k}x^{2k})$$

Then you can use the Cauhcy product formula.

---

Now for the Cauchy product

$$\sum_0^\infty c_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n )(\sum_0^\infty b_nx^{n})$$

Let $a_n=1$ and $b_{2k}=1,b_{2k+1} = 0$, we conclude

$$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k a_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^nb_k $$

Let us see the case for even $n = 2j$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2j} b_k =\sum_{k=0}^{j} b_{2k} +\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} b_{2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{j} 1 = j + 1 = \frac{n}{2} +1 $$

Let us see the case for odd $n = 2j +1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2j+1} b_k =\sum_{k=0}^{j} b_{2k} +\sum_{k=0}^{j} b_{2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{j} 1 = j + 1 = \frac{n-1}{2} +1 $$

We deduce that

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor+1 \right)x^n$$

Now since $$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor+1 =\frac{3+(-1)^n+2n}{4}$$

We conclude that

> $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}
>  \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(3+(-1)^n+2n}{4} \right)x^n$$

---

Another example

[Calculate the series expansion at $x=0$ of the integral $\int \frac{xy\arctan(xy)}{1-xy}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164449/calculate-the-series-expansion-at-x-0-of-the-integral-int-fracxy-arctanxy/2164633#2164633)

Comment: What's the reason behind $b_{2k+1} = 0$

Comment: @math31 ... in order to be able to write the second series under the form $\sum_k b_k x^k$, that's all...

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks edited accordingly.

Comment: Very clear like this!

Comment: I have provided another answer (the first one I wrote was too complicated).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the statement for convergent series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)$$ implies that

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k\right)\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^m x^{2k}\right)$$

In particular we have the case

$$\begin{align}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} x^k\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2k}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2k}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n} x^{k}\chi_{2\Bbb N}(k)\right)\end{align}$$

provided that each series converges. From here is easy to use the Cauchy product to define the $a_k$ where the function $\chi_{2\Bbb N}$ is defined as

$$\chi_{2\Bbb N}(k):=\begin{cases}1,& k\in 2\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\\0,&k\notin 2\Bbb N_{\ge 0}\end{cases}$$