# What is $a_n$, if $\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n = (\sum_0^\infty x^n )(\sum_0^\infty x^{2n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found a answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174836/533661
But why the answer uses $\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$? To use that, we must assume $|x|<1$, but the question does not assume that.

And how the answer got $a_n$ from $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}, a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+1$

Comment: If $|x|\geq1$ then the RHS isn't well-defined so the problem only makes sense for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Even if you intend this as an equality of formal power series, it still must hold within the radius of convergence on the right, so working with $|x|<1$ can't hurt.

Comment: @lulu why as a formal power series, the RHS still need to be convergent?

Comment: I didn't say it needed to be convergent.  But it is convergent if $|x|<1$ and if I can solve the problem in that region, I've solved it everywhere.

Comment: If we interpret both sides as formal power series, then we do not have to worry about convergence. Indeed, $$(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=1$$ holds in the ring of formal power series, and so, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=(1-x)^{-1}$$ holds.

Comment: @lulu So is it that basically that since $a_n$ is not dependent on $x$, so we can find $a_n$ when series converges, then the $a_n$  is also the same for the divergent series?

Comment: @SangchulLee I haven't learnt ring yet, but would mind explain a little more why they hold in the ring of formal power series?

Comment: It is actually much easier than you might worry. The concept of formal power series is analogous to that of polynomials, and all the familiar arithmetic operations extends in a natural way. For example, \begin{gather*}(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots)\\=a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2)x^2+\dots.\end{gather*}Then, $$(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots)=1+(1-1)x+(1-1)x^2+\dots=1$$ and so, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ is the reciprocal of $1-x$, i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Then why this is not contradict to $\sum_{n=0}^{n}x^n=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, when $|x|>1$, the the sum goes to infinity?

Comment: Recall that a polynomial is just a formal expression and the corresponding polynomial function is obtained by 'evaluating' that polynomial at each point. Likewise, a formal power series is literally a formal expression, and then convergent power series can be thought as obtained by evaluating formal power series on the interval of convergence. Of course, a notion of limit can be defined for formal power series as well, but that is slightly different from what we normally encounter in convergent power series. (This is the price when we break free of the notion of convergence!)

Comment: More precisely, a sequence of formal power series $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^{(n)}_jx^j$ is said to converges if the sequence $(a^{(n)}_j)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of the coefficients of $x^j$ eventually becomes constant for each $j$. So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots$$holds in the ring of formal power series because each coefficient of the $j$-th term eventually becomes $1$.

Comment: So this leaves one crucial question: Are the results obtained via formal power series and convergent power series the same? And the answer is thankfully yes (under reasonable assumptions, such as positive radius of convergence).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, I think I need some more background knowledge to understand the whole thing, but I kind of have a idea what's going on!

Comment: No worries. To summarize, the point is that you can play either at 'expression level' (such as formal power series) or at 'function level' (such as convergent power series). The former approach allows us not to be concerned with convergence, but at the same time, this also means that limiting argument is very restricted in this approach. The latter approach forces us to worry about the convergence issue, but then we can also employ various limiting arguments. Of course, either one is acceptable since both yields the same answer under reasonable assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{2m} = \frac{1}{(1-x)} \frac{1}{(1-x^2)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply top & bottom by $(1+x)$ and split the function into its odd & even powers.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1+x}{(1-x^2)^2} &=& \color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}} +\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2} \\
&=& \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1) x^{2i}} +\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1) x^{2i+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The above series can be considered as "Formal Power series" to represent the sequence $1,1,2,2,3,3,\cdots$ and for combinatorialists their convergence in an analytic sense is not of interest.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

For the second point:

If we put $$b_n=a_{2n+1}$$
then

$$b_n=a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+1=b_{n-1}+1$$
thus $ (b_n) $ is arithmetic. So,

$$b_n=b_0+n=a_1+n=a_{2n+1}$$

and
$$a_{2n}=a_{2n+1}=a_1+n$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we could write it this way:

$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n &= \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j \right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^j x^{2k} \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{j+2k} \\
\end{aligned} 
$$
but if we notice that
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty  x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
and
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty  x^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
so that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
we could make use of the coefficients for the McLauren series.  Better yet, write this as a partial fraction expansion (as was done over at the link to the solution) and read off the coefficients.

Both series converge if and only if $|x|<1$, so that is understood.